# Iterate through a list of booleans in order to create a new list of integers

Tags: python, list, for-loop, boolean, increment

**I would like to turn this list of booleans:**

```
bool_list: [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
```

**Into this list of integers:**

```
int_li = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Basicaly, iterate through the list of booleans and incremente 1 everytime the value is True. Any efficient way to do that ?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you share what you got/tried so far?

Comment: I got an .xlsx file with every tennis matches of the Atp tour. Each row is a match, with the variables 'Location', 'Date', 'Winner' and 'Loser'. I would like to create a line plot, where x-axis would be the date and y-axis would be the amount of victories each player has.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Python 3.8 or later, you could make use of the walrus operator to generate your desired result using a list comprehension, making use of the fact that in an integer context, `True == 1` and `False == 0`:

```py
v = 0
int_li = [v := v+b for b in bool_list]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Interesting to know `warlus` can be used inside List Comp. TIL.  Thx

Comment: @DanielHao yeah - it's a pretty cool addition to the language. Now if only there was a null coalescing operator then you could even get rid of the requirement for initialisation

Answer (score 3):

Create a variable (e.g. `count` with a value of 0, loop through each item in the list and every time it is `True`, add +1 to `count`. Then append `count` to the new list like so:

```
bool_list = [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]
int_li = []
count = 0
for item in bool_list:
    if item:
        count += 1
    int_li.append(count)
print(int_li)
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import accumulate

int_li = list(map(int, accumulate(bool_list)))
```

As Daniel Hao pointed out, pure `accumulate` doesn't work, as the first element will remain `bool`, resulting in `[False, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]`.
Mapping to `int` is the simplest fix I saw, though I don't like it much.

Another way, with an initial 0 that we then disregard:

```
from itertools import accumulate

_, *int_li = accumulate(bool_list, initial=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

simply do this with list comprehension in one line:

```
bool_list = [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]

int_list = [sum(bool_list[:i+1]) for i in range(len(bool_list))]
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```